# Does msbuild know if its called from visual studio versus command line?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

My build is running just fine when called from command line, but fails when built through visual studio. I found the issue to be related to how `WindowsTargetPlatformVersion` is treated in these different cases.

Id like to skip a certain build step when building in the IDE for development but leave it when building from command line. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found `BuildingInsideVisualStudio` that did the trick